# It seems like my java code is stuck in a loop somewhere

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.lang.String;
public class GameOfNim
{
  private int min,max;
  private int turn;
  private int firstturn;
  private int stupid;
  private int smart;
  private int computer;
  private int user;
  private int first;
  private int pile;
    public GameOfNim(int min, int max ){
    pile=(int)(Math.random()*max+min);
    smart=(int)(Math.random()*100);
    stupid=(int)(Math.random()*100);
    System.out.println("Pile size is "+pile);
    firstturn=(int)(Math.random()*100 + 1);
    computer=0;
    user=1;
    if(firstturn>50)
    {
        firstturn=user;
    }
    else
    {
        firstturn=computer;
    }
    firstturn=turn;
 }

 public void play()
 {
     if(smart>50)
        {
            System.out.println("Computer is playing smart");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Computer is playing stupid");
        }

     if(firstturn==user)
             {
                 System.out.println("You go first");
             }

             else
             {
                 System.out.println("Computer goes first");
             }
          turn = firstturn;
     while(pile-1>0)
     {
         if(turn==user)
         { 
            String take = "How many marbles do you want to take away?";
            System.out.println(take);
            int take2 = Integer.parseInt(take);   
            while(take2>(int)(pile/2))
            {
              System.out.println("Only take away half or less from the pile");
              take = "How many marbles do you want to take away?";
              take2= Integer.parseInt(take);
            }
            pile= pile-take2;
            System.out.println("There are "+pile+" marbles left");
            turn=computer;
                }  
          else
          {
              if(smart>50)
              {
                  pile -= smartTake();
              } 

              else
              {
                  pile -= stupidTake();
              }   
              turn = user;
            }
        }   
    }

 private int smartTake() 
    {
        int x = (int)(Math.random())*2-1;
        int sMarbles= (int)Math.pow(2,x);
        while (sMarbles > (.5 * pile) || sMarbles==0)
        {
            x = (int)(Math.random())*2-1;
            sMarbles = (int)Math.pow(2,x);
        }
        System.out.println("The computer took away " + sMarbles +" marbles");
        return sMarbles;
    }

    private int stupidTake(){
        int stMarbles = pile/2;
        while (stMarbles > (.5*pile) || pile==0)
        {
            stMarbles = pile/2;
        }
        System.out.println("The Computer took away " + stMarbles +" marbles");
        return stMarbles;
    }
}
```

**this is my game of nim class**

```
public class Project5
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
      String k = "yes";
      String str;

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the minimum number of marbles in your pile: ");
        int min = console.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the maximum number of marbles in your pile: ");
        int max= console.nextInt();
        GameOfNim game = new GameOfNim(min, max);

        game.play();

      System.out.println( " Thank you and good bye!");
    }
}
```

**and this is my driver class**

for some reason everytime i run it it goes all the way to the point where it says "Computer goes first" then nothing else happens. im assuming its stuck in a loop but i cant seem to find out why. any help will be appreciated

Comment: I would suggest that you learn to use a debugger.  Simply stepping through your code, line by line, would probably reveal more than having someone on SO try to find the bug(s).

Comment: firstturn=turn; in this line  can you tell me the value of turn

Comment: sorry it took a while to respond but i figured out what the problem was with the help of what user7790438 said. the firstturn= turn was a mistake as it would always be 0 regardless. fixed a couple of other errors as well. thanks!